# Testing Material UI Radio Checked Value

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, material-ui, react-hooks

- I have a functional component written in React with Redux using React
  Hooks.
- I am testing using Jest with Enzyme.
- The component renders Material UI Radio buttons **(code example below):**

```
<RadioGroup>
  <FormControlLabel
    value="batchName"
    label="Batch Name"
    name="batchName"
    control={
      <Radio
        disableRipple
        name="batchName"
        color="primary"
        checked={searchBy === 'batchName'}
        onClick={() => {dispatch(actions.setBatchSearchBy('batchName'))}}
      />
    }
  />
  <FormControlLabel
    value="firstPaymentDate"
    label="First Payment Date"
    name="firstPaymentDate"
    control={
      <Radio:
        disableRipple
        name="firstPaymentDate"
        color="primary"
        checked={searchBy === 'firstPaymentDate'}
        onClick={() => {dispatch(actions.setBatchSearchBy('firstPaymentDate'))}}
      />
    }
  />
</RadioGroup>
```

**Test file:**

```
import React from 'react';
import { BatchHeaderComponent } from '../../../components/batchManagement/BatchHeaderComponent';
import configureStore from '../../../store';
import {Provider} from "react-redux";
import Enzyme, { mount } from "enzyme";
import Adapter from "enzyme-adapter-react-16";
import Radio from "@material-ui/core/Radio";

Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

describe('BatchHeaderComponent', () => {
  it('mounts to the DOM with its sub-components', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(<Provider store={configureStore()}>
      <BatchHeaderComponent/>
    </Provider>);
    expect(wrapper.find(BatchHeaderComponent)).toBeDefined();
  });

  it('changes searchBy when a new option has been selected', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(<Provider store={configureStore()}>
      <BatchHeaderComponent />
    </Provider>);
    const radio = wrapper.find(Radio).last();
    console.log(radio.debug());
    // radio.simulate('change', {target: {name: 'firstPaymentDate', checked: true}});
    // radio.prop('onChange', {target: { name: 'firstPaymentDate', checked: true}});
    radio.simulate('click');
    console.log(radio.debug());
    expect(radio.props().checked).toEqual(true);
  });
});
```

I can't get the 'checked' value to change when simulating a 'click' or 'change' event.

Regardless of which path I take, the checked value remains false.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: I am trying to test the onChange method for coveralls code coverage.

Answer (score 4):

I figured it out. I needed to run wrapper.find again to see the updated change.

```
  it('changes searchBy when a new option has been selected', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(<Provider store={configureStore()}>
      <BatchHeaderComponent />
    </Provider>);
    const radio = wrapper.find(Radio).last();
    radio.simulate('click');
    expect(wrapper.find(Radio).last().props().checked).toEqual(true);
  });
```